# Android - Count the number of files in a server directory

Tags: java, android, file, uri

I'm having trouble with simply counting the number of files stored on one of my directories on a server.

I'm an Android beginner and I know I must be making a simple mistake with my code

```
File file = null;
   try {
       file = new File(new URI("http://myURL/directory/userImages/"));
   } 
   catch (URISyntaxException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   Log.d(TAG, "Num of Files: " + file.list().length);
```

I'm getting a URI exception:

```
Expected file scheme in URI: http://myURL/directory/userImages/
```

I can't seem to find out the problem here. It's obviously a problem with the URI.

Any help or info would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: in my understanding this is not possible using files, you have to use http client to communicate with the server and have to use some server    scripting languages which will get you the result like PHP, You android app communicate with the server page and fetch you the result

Comment: Hmmm ok, thanks rajesh.adhi. That seems a reasonable work around, I just thought it was possible without the need for a server side script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work as the URI constructor of the `File` class that you are using only works with file URIs as documented in the [JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.net.URI%29). Concretely this means that your URI has the start with "file://", which in itself means that you can only access local files (or files on remote systems mounted as local drives on your system).

I'm not sure what the exact context is of this particular piece of code, but I'm pretty sure that what you are trying to achieve will need some more complex code.

Particularly, as far as I now, it is not possible to fetch a directory via HTTP. I think you might need FTP/SSH/... access to the particular system to solve this.

If you give some more context, I (or others) might be able to give some more help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Joris. Well what I'm trying to do is to create a simple remote image viewer with next and previous buttons. The images will be uploaded by users to my server so the file count will always change. However, I want to initially know how many images are on the directory so I can know when to disable the next button for example. Or possibly to format the image urls dynamically by naming them 0.jpg, 1.jpg etc

Comment: Similar to what rajesh.adhi said, you will need a server side programming language (PHP, ASP, Java, Ruby, Python, ...) to do that. The 'usual' solution would be to create a dynamic webpage that accepts file uploads (your image) through POST requests and then saves the uploaded file to your directory of choice (meanwhile counting the number of files/images in that directory). This shouldn't be to hard if you Google a bit on it.

Comment: Yea I think that's the route I'm going to take. So far I haven't looked at uploading the images but your suggestion sounds the most likely. I have a bit of experience with PHP so I guess I'll see how I get on. Thanks again!